# Reinstall Rails every time I restart my computer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, macos

My issue concerns my inability to keep a working version of RoR on my mac OSX 10.6.8. I've been working through various books that teach Rails, but the biggest issue I keep running into is that the Rails installation seems to disappear whenever I restart my computer. I have a directory on my desktop, within which I put all of my Rails projects. Whenever I attempt to open that folder in terminal and create a new rails app,

```
rails new examplename
```

I get met with this error:

```
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/dependency.rb:313:in `to_specs': 
Could not find 'rails' (>= 0) among 12 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)
Checked in 
'GEM_PATH=/Users/greyelerson/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547:/Users/greyelerson/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3- p547@global', execute `gem env` for more information
from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/dependency.rb:322:in `to_spec'
from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:58:in `gem'
from /usr/bin/rails:18
```

The only "solution" which has allowed me to continue thus far has been to completely reinstall ruby and then reinstall rails every time I want to work.  There has got to be a real and permanent fix for this. Please help.

Comment: You completely reinstall Ruby *OVER* the version of Ruby that Apple installed? "[Is it possible to reinstall/fix Mac OS X's system ruby without doing a complete OS reinstall?](http://superuser.com/questions/171433/is-it-possible-to-reinstall-fix-mac-os-xs-system-ruby-without-doing-a-complete/175858#175858)" might be useful to you.

Comment: @elersong, you could have a look here on how to install rvm in your mac http://www.computersnyou.com/2673/2013/10/install-ruby-rails-macos-x-mavericks-10-9-mysql-step-step/

Answer (score 1):

Rather than installing Rails into the system version of Ruby, I would recommend that you instead install your own copy of Ruby in your home directory using [RVM.](https://rvm.io/) That way, your changes won't conflict with the system's changes. For example, if Apple decides to update Ruby to a new version that's incompatible with your version of Rails, you're still safe because you have your own version in your home directory. You can also install multiple versions of Ruby if you want to test your code with beta versions or whatever.

Comment: RVM, or rbenv, are both good, however, people don't pay attention to how RVM is supposed to be installed, so it's *really* important to read through, and follow, the directions at the [RVM installation page](http://rvm.io/rvm/install).